# Why doesn't factoring out with a DefaultExpression in a TDataSet work

Tags: postgresql, delphi, firedac

I am working with the Delphi FireDac technology in connection with a PostgreSQL database. I would like to set a floating value as DefaultExpression for a Field at Runtime. 
The next lines works fine:

```
FDMemTable1.FieldByName( 'some_fieldname').FieldKind  := fkData;
FDMemTable1.FieldByName( 'some_fieldname').DefaultExpression := '5.5';
```

But when I try to factor this out with the next code, I get an error:
Exception class EFDException with message '[FireDAC][Stan][Eval]-104. Type mismatch in expression'.

```
procedure SetDefaultFieldValue (
    var aFDMemTable : TFDMemTable;
    aFieldName  : string;
    aFieldValue : string;
    aFieldKind  : TFieldKind );
  begin
    aFDMemTable.FieldByName( aFieldName ).FieldKind  := aFieldKind;
    aFDMemTable.FieldByName( aFieldName ).DefaultExpression :=  QuotedStr( aFieldValue );
  end;
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

Thanks all for the suggestions. The problem seems to be - as @Graig Young pointed out- the different kind of columns (Numeric or String etc).
I needed the **QuotedStr** for the String-Fields. Otherwise I get an error:

> [aFieldValue] Column or Function is not found. Add
>   FireDAC.Stan.ExprFuncs to the uses clause (which I have)

So @Victoria, leaving out **QuotedStr** works indeed for the Numeric-Field, but factoring like the next lines doesn't work for String-Fields.

```
procedure SetDefaultFieldValue (
    var aFDMemTable : TFDMemTable;
    aFieldName  : string;
    aFieldValue : string;
    aFieldKind  : TFieldKind );
  begin
    aFDMemTable.FieldByName( aFieldName ).FieldKind  := aFieldKind;
    aFDMemTable.FieldByName( aFieldName ).DefaultExpression :=  aFieldValue;
  end;
```

**DefaultExpression**  expects a string-value. 
Trying to refine my question:
Is it possible to factor-out DefaultExpression for "any" FieldType? 
if so, how?

Comment: This is not a [mcve] The "_type mismatch_" error message suggests you might be trying to set a string default for a numeric column. I suggest you [edit] and fix your question.

Comment: Please read the link on [mcve]s. The sooner you learn to do this, the much easier time you'll have asking coding questions (and not just here).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for any unclearness, but the next code avoids the mentioned errors.

```
procedure SetDefaultFieldValue(
    var aFDMemTable : TFDMemTable;
    aFieldName      : string;
    aFieldValue     : string;
    aFieldType      : TFieldType);
  begin
    aFDMemTable.FieldByName( aFieldName ).FieldKind  := fkData;

    case aFieldType of
      ftString  : aFDMemTable.FieldByName( aFieldName ).DefaultExpression :=  QuotedStr( aFieldValue ) ;
      ftSingle  : aFDMemTable.FieldByName( aFieldName ).DefaultExpression :=  aFieldValue ;
      ftInteger : aFDMemTable.FieldByName( aFieldName ).DefaultExpression :=  aFieldValue ;
    end;

  end;
```

As @Graig Young mentioned the way of handling String-Fields should be different form Numeric-Fields.

Now the next code works.

```
SetDefaultFieldValue( aAliasTable.FDMemTable1, 'some_fieldname', 'a_string_value' , ftString );
SetDefaultFieldValue( aAliasTable.FDMemTable1, 'another_fieldname', '5.5' , ftSingle );
```

Thanks to all!

Comment: What about the other data types?

Comment: @Victoria This code obviously isn't complete. I think it is curious that Strings-Fields must be Quoted. I am using Seatttle.

Comment: Aha, so it's an example. Well, to be honest, I've never used this property before. Rather than that I would preferably assign `Value` to the field.

Comment: If you want to be pedantic, then remove the `var` parameter on aFDMemTable (because you are not actually changing it), and add `const` to all the others.

Comment: @Alister. I believe you, but can you explain this? Is changing the properties of an object something different than changing the object?

Comment: The parameter `aFDMemTable` is basically a pointer into memory where a `TFDMemTable` resides, and you are not changing the pointer.  If you did something like `aFDMemTable := TFDMemTable.Create(Self);`, then you'd need to pass it as a `var` parameter

Comment: Ok, that's clear. And what about the other side? I mean, does it create possible problems to use var before aFDMemTable here?